# Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't seem to solve this issue. I have other controllers done in the same way that work fine but this one gives an error 
`Error: ng:areq Bad Argument"  "Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`. Here is my code:

```
//js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
              $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<@');
              $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('@>');
        });

(function(){

     var myContacts = angular.module('myApp');

     myContacts.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


            $scope.totalContacts = 0;
            $scope.request_limit = 3; // this should match however many results your API puts on one page

            $scope.pagination = {
                current: 1
            };

            getContacts(1); 

            // Page changed
            $scope.pageChanged = function(newPage) {

                getContacts(newPage);
            };


            // Get function 
            $scope.getContacts = function(pageNumber){

                api_url = '/api/people/list?page=' + pageNumber;


                $http.get(api_url).success(function(data){


                    // Update the scope data
                    $scope.contacts = data.data;
                    $scope.totalContacts = data.count

                    console.log('Data: '+ $scope.contacts);

                    // Prepare message output
                    if(data.code == 9999) {

                        // Show error
                        displayMessage('Error', data.msg);

                    } else if (data.code == 8888) {

                        // Show error
                        displayMessage('Error', data.msg);

                    } else if (data.code == 1001) {

                        // No data
                        // Show info
                        displayMessage('Info', data.msg);

                    } else if (data.code == 1000) { 

                        // OK, update the scope
                        $scope.contacts = data.data;
                        hideMessage();
                    }
                });
            }   
        });
})();

// html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>...
 <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl"  class="container-fluid" id="pcont">
  <table class="table no-border hover">
   <thead class="no-border">
    <tr>
     <th class="text-center"><strong>Position</strong></th>
     <th class="text-center"><strong>Organization</strong></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="no-border-y">
    <tr dir-paginate="contact in contacts | itemsPerPage: request_limit" total-items="totalContacts"  current-page="pagination.current">
     <td class="text-center"><@ contact.contact_position @></td>
     <td class="text-center"><@ contact.organization_name @></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody> 
  </table>
```

What have I done wrong there?

Comment: Your formatting is tough to read. I've gotten this error when there's something wrong with syntax. No reason to prefix with data- unless you care about validators.

Comment: Shouldn't you call `$scope.getContacts(1); ` instead of just `getContacts(1); ` ?

Comment: @IvanSivak I think so too (just posted that same guess), additionally it needs to be at the end of the function, because it will not be declared at that line.

Answer (score 6):

This line in your controller function probably throws an error, because such a function is not defined:

`getContacts(1);`

Because of this, the controller is not correctly defined so you get the error that you received by angular.
Try removing that line and instead putting this at the end of your controller function:

```
$scope.getContacts(1);
```

As a side note, you have the same mistake in the `$scope.pageChanged` function.
There you should replace `getContacts` by `$scope.getContacts` as well.

Comment: done all that, problem is still there and I added it in  (function(){... })(); block because I read in other posts that's how to get rid of the error, but it obviously doesn't work for me.

Comment: Its finally sorted. You are right  getContacts() was the issue. But I had strip out all the html inside <div data-ng-controller="contactsCtrl" class="row"> for it to throw the right error message.  Added $scope.getContacts() and called the functions at the end of controller function and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Weird though I thought that's how functions work, I gues not in AngularJS.

Comment: It makes a difference how you declare a function. If you declare it as `$scope.xxx = function() {...}`, then the function becomes a property of `$scope` and is only available after that line. If you declare it like `function xxx() {...}`, *function hoisting* comes into play - the function is then available even before the declaration. If you want to learn more about this behaviour, hoisting is the keyword to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of controller is kinda weird.
Its kinda weird because your controller is not bootstrap with your application.

You can implement controller in these ways :

**Method:1**

```
          var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

        myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
              $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<@');
              $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('@>');

        });
       myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
         // .. Rest of the controller code
```

Take a look in this guide : 
[Angular controller guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

**Method: 2.**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl)

function myCtrl($location, common , config) {

}
```

Please check John papa angular convention here 
[John Papa Convention](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers)

Comment: may be it weird but its not explain why its not working

Comment: @Zamboney already updated the answer this is for the convention only sorry

Answer (score 0):

Still not getting, why you enclosed the controller in a function(), try this:

```
//js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
              $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<@');
              $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('@>');
        });

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


            $scope.totalContacts = 0;
            $scope.request_limit = 3; // this should match however many results your API puts on one page

            $scope.pagination = {
                current: 1
            };

            getContacts(1); 

            // Page changed
            $scope.pageChanged = function(newPage) {

                getContacts(newPage);
            };


            // Get function 
            $scope.getContacts = function(pageNumber){

                api_url = '/api/people/list?page=' + pageNumber;


                $http.get(api_url).success(function(data){


                    // Update the scope data
                    $scope.contacts = data.data;
                    $scope.totalContacts = data.count

                    console.log('Data: '+ $scope.contacts);

                    // Prepare message output
                    if(data.code == 9999) {

                        // Show error
                        displayMessage('Error', data.msg);

                    } else if (data.code == 8888) {

                        // Show error
                        displayMessage('Error', data.msg);

                    } else if (data.code == 1001) {

                        // No data
                        // Show info
                        displayMessage('Info', data.msg);

                    } else if (data.code == 1000) { 

                        // OK, update the scope
                        $scope.contacts = data.data;
                        hideMessage();
                    }
                });
            }   
        });

// html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>...
 <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl"  class="container-fluid" id="pcont">
  <table class="table no-border hover">
   <thead class="no-border">
    <tr>
     <th class="text-center"><strong>Position</strong></th>
     <th class="text-center"><strong>Organization</strong></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="no-border-y">
    <tr dir-paginate="contact in contacts | itemsPerPage: request_limit" total-items="totalContacts"  current-page="pagination.current">
     <td class="text-center"><@ contact.contact_position @></td>
     <td class="text-center"><@ contact.organization_name @></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody> 
  </table>
```

Comment: same as what i meant :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find error in your code as it is quite tough format . I am just giving a try so try it .

```
(function () {
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

    myApp.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<@');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('@>');
    });

    var myContacts = angular.module('myApp');

    myContacts.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


        $scope.totalContacts = 0;
        $scope.request_limit = 3; // this should match however many results your API puts on one page

        $scope.pagination = {
            current: 1
        };

        $scope.getContacts(1);

        // Page changed
        $scope.pageChanged = function (newPage) {

             $scope.getContacts(newPage);
        };


        // Get function 
        $scope.getContacts = function (pageNumber) {

            api_url = '/api/people/list?page=' + pageNumber;


            $http.get(api_url).success(function (data) {


                // Update the scope data
                $scope.contacts = data.data;
                $scope.totalContacts = data.count

                console.log('Data: ' + $scope.contacts);

                // Prepare message output
                if (data.code == 9999) {

                    // Show error
                    displayMessage('Error', data.msg);

                } else if (data.code == 8888) {

                    // Show error
                    displayMessage('Error', data.msg);

                } else if (data.code == 1001) {

                    // No data
                    // Show info
                    displayMessage('Info', data.msg);

                } else if (data.code == 1000) {

                    // OK, update the scope
                    $scope.contacts = data.data;
                    hideMessage();
                }
            });
        }
    });
})();// JavaScript source code
```